# Firebase Authentication Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been working with Firebase for authentication purposes and I can get it to work as long as there are two alert methods like so:

```
var x;
var y; 

function boo() {
   if (document.getElementById('email') !== null && document.getElementById('password') !== null) {
      x = document.getElementById("email").value;
      y = document.getElementById('password').value;
      alert(x);
      alert(y);
      const auth = firebase.auth();
      auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(x, y);
      } else {
            ...
      }
}
```

However, if I remove the two alert methods then nothing is sent nor displayed in Firebase and I'm not seeing any errors within the console. I was hoping someone knew what is going on because I don't want to display the email and password every time someone signs up.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form class="signupForm">
    <input type="email" class="inputs" onblur="validateForm()" id="email" required name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" class="inputs" id="password" required name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <button id="btn" class="buttons" onclick="boo()">Signup</button>
</form>
```

Comment: When you remove the alerts, what are the values of x and y before the create user line?

Comment: add to createUserWithEmailAndPassword 'then' and 'catch' and log the response to see what is going on

Comment: They're just declared without any value.

Comment: @mur7ay can you show me the html code that contain email and password inputs ?

Comment: @badisMerabet I've added the HTML as well

Comment: Weird to say, but please replace <form> tags with <div> and try again.

Comment: I've replaced the form tags with a div and it's now showing an error based off the code you provided below. The error reads: Uncaught ReferenceError: logUser is not defined
    at auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword.then.errorCode (userSignup.js:42)
    at e.Sa (firebase-auth.js:76)
    at Ld (firebase-auth.js:80)
    at Hd (firebase-auth.js:80)
    at D.qf (firebase-auth.js:79)
    at dd (firebase-auth.js:70)
    at <anonymous>

Comment: remove logUser(user); it's useless . or replace it with console.log( user) to show currently  created user infos.

Comment: Ok, I've deleted logUser() and replaced it with console.log(user) which seems to be sending the data to Firebase now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `<form>` tags with `<div>`

Use this code to check for errors:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
password).then(function(user) {
   var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   console.log(user); // Optional
}, function(error) {
   // Handle Errors here.
   var errorCode = error.code;
   var errorMessage = error.message;
});
```

Check your firebase config infos:

```
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Also in firebase console -> authentication, check that Sign-in method email/password is enabled

[image]

Comment: let me know what's displayed in console

Comment: I added what you suggested but no message was displayed within the console.

Comment: However, when I added this: auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(x, y).then(function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });  I got code: "auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred"

Comment: I have updated my answer. try again and let me know.

Comment: Still nothing unfortunately.

Comment: Happy for you :) !

Comment: I was having the same issue and replacing the form tags with div's fixed the problem. do you know why that is an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault`,  like below:

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const email = event.target.elements.email.value;
    const password = event.target.elements.password.value;
    // alert(email)
    // alert(password)
    await createNewUserWithFirebase(email, password);
}
```